# Week Number when week starts on Friday

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write SQL to populate a customer calendar table in which the business week for the customer is Friday to Thursday.  I will need to populate for several customers that each have a different business week defined.  I am trying to populate the following fields:

```
WeekBeginDate
WeekEndDate
WeekNo
WeekYear
```

This is an example of the result set:

```
Date      WeekBeginDate  WeekEndDate    DayofWeek   WeekNo   WeekYear
01/03/13  12/28/12       01/03/2013     Thursday    52       2012
01/04/13  01/04/13       01/10/2013     Friday  1    2013
```

Comment: Populated based on what? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Based on your result set, how will you distinguish one customer's week from another customer's? And what does "DayofWeek" mean? (01/03/2013 and 01/10/2013 are both on Thursday.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a Dates table with the date range you need to avoid looping.  Then, you can take advantage of SET DATEFIRST to vary the first day of the week:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598(v=sql.105).aspx

Then, the following should return the correct results.  The following is using your Friday example.  I also included a "CustomerID" in the list, just in case you need to vary by customer.

```
--Set the first day of the week as Friday.  For other customers with different week start days, vary this setting
set datefirst 5

select 
    1 AS CustomerID,  --or whatever you use as a customerid
    CalendarDate, 
    dateadd(dd, (-1 * datepart(dw, calendardate)) + 1, calendardate) as WeekBeginDate,
    dateadd(dd, (7 - datepart(dw, calendardate)), calendardate) as WeekEndDate,
    datename(dw, calendardate) as DayofWeek,
    datepart(wk, dateadd(dd, (-1 * datepart(dw, calendardate)) + 1, calendardate)) - 1 as Week No,
    datepart(yyyy, dateadd(dd, (-1 * datepart(dw, calendardate)) + 1, calendardate)) as WeekYear
FROM
    dates  --my dates table
where
    calendardate between '12/28/12' and '1/5/14'
```

Comment: This SQL works great for most dates; however, it does not work if the first day of the week is also the first day of the year.  In my example, Friday was the start of the week; therefore 1/1/2010 and 1/1/2016 return 0 as the WeekNo.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the dates for seeding, you can use something like this:

```
Select DateAdd (D, ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By C1.Ordinal_Position), '12/31/1999') DateValue
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2
```

If you run the above query in a database with too few columns, then change the FROM to be.  Cartesian product FTW

```
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2, 
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C3, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C4
```

Now, you need a different day of the week to be the first day.  So read up on [SET DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx).  This lets you set the first day of week for a particular session to TSQL.

Then you can then use [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to get the other columns that you require.

Combine the three to get your answer.  I am going to give you a sample of how you can make this work - you can use DATEADD to the query to get Start-Of-Week and End-Of-Week values, and DATEPART to get Week-Of-Year and YearN-umber

```
SET DATEFIRST 3 -- put your corresponding day here

;With AllDates AS
(
Select 
    DateAdd (D, ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By C1.Ordinal_Position), '12/31/1999') DateValue
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1
),
AllDatesWithWeekDayNumber AS
(
Select 
    DateValue, 
    DatePart (weekday, DateValue) WeekDayNumber
From AllDates
)
Select * From AllDatesWithWeekDayNumber
```